# Creating a http Client in Cake 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am having trouble getting a response from an API using a `http Client` in Cake PHP 3

I want to send the following `GET` request but I cannot manage to return a result. If visit this url with a browser i get a response.

```
http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8020/mvapireq/?apientry=newuseru&authkey=XXXXXXXXXX&u_username=NEWUSERNAME&u_password=PASSWORD&u_name=NAME&u_email=EMAIL&u_phone=PHONE&u_currency=USD&u_country=USA&u_address=x&deviceid=DEVICEID&now=555
```

When I try to send the same request with `http Client` my reponse object is always `null`

```
use Cake\Network\Http\Client;
use Cake\Network\Http\Response;

public function foo(){    
    $http = new Client();
    $data = [
        'apientry' => 'newuseru',
        'authkey' => 'XXXXXXXX',
        'u_username' => 'NEWUSERNAME',
        'u_password' => 'PASSWORD',
        'u_name' => 'NAME',
        'u_email' => 'EMAIL',
        'u_phone' => 'PHONE',
        'u_currency' => 'USD',
        'u_country' => 'USA',
        'u_address' => 'x',
        'deviceid' => 'DEVICEID',
        'now' => '555'
    ];

    $response = $http->get('http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8020/mvapireq', $data);

    debug($response->body);
    debug($response->code);
    debug($response->headers);
}
```

This is the results from the `debug()` it seems to me like the request is not being sent.

```
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 1159]

/src/Controller/UsersController.php (line 1159)

null

Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 1160]

/src/Controller/UsersController.php (line 1160)

null

Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 1161]

/src/Controller/UsersController.php (line 1161)

null

/src/Controller/UsersController.php (line 1163)

null
```

I've tried many different ways of structuring `$http` and all of them have returned the same result. I really can't figure out whats going wrong. Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you load http client via ```use Cake\Network\Http\Client;``` ?

Comment: Yes I did, I also included `use Cake\Network\Http\Response;` just to be sure. I've edited my post

Comment: What's the debug result for `$reponse`? Are you sure it's a `GET` request here? I'd expect a `POST` request for this.

Comment: `debug($response);` returns `null`. I've also tried changing it to `$http->post(....` add got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `hostname` and `port` in the constructor of the `Client`:

```
<?php  
 use Cake\Network\Http\Client;
 // ....
 public function foo(){    

    $http = new Client([
        'hostname' => 'XX.XX.XX.XX',
        'port' => '8020'
    ]);

 $data = [
    'apientry' => 'newuseru',
    //....
    'now' => '555'
 ];

 $response = $http->get('/mvapireq', $data);
 // ...
}
```

And check your system:

- firewall (os)
- allow_url_fopen (in your php runtime configuration)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but still get the same `null` results. Also any values set in the constructor are overwritten by values in the `get` function. According to the Cake docs, anyway.

Comment: But in get you try '/mvapireq' or '/mvapireq/' (without and with "/" at the end?)

    $response = $http->get('/mvapireq', $data);

or

    $response = $http->get('/mvapireq/', $data);

Comment: Yeah, I've tried every combination of stuff in  the `constructor`/`get` method I could think of. I've come to the conclusion that Cake didnt like the port. I've since scrapped the `http Client` and used cURL instead.

Comment: the code above works for me,  i think the problem is in your system/configuration.... 
 * firewall?
 * allow_url_fopen?