# Under what circumstances will Cake3's HTTP Client return a NULL response?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to connect to an API using Cake's `HTTP Client`. But the response object that is returned is `null`, no status code, no body, nothing, just `null`. It's worth noting that if I visit the URL from a browser I get the desired results.

I asked a question to see if I was doing anything stupid which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613517/creating-a-http-client-in-cake-3). Judging by the lack of responses I dont think I have any silly syntax errors.

So now I'm wondering what has to happen for the Cake3 `HTTP Client` to return `NULL` rather than a `response` object? Hopefully knowing what could be going wrong will show me where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Under what circumstances will Cake3's HTTP Client return a NULL response?

When the adapter returns an empty array (ie no response objects), or a non-array value. The client uses `array_pop()` on the adapters return value, which would return `null` in case of an empty array, or a non-array value.

In order to debug the problem, dig into the adapter code and check where things are going wrong. Unless you are using a custom adapter, that would be `\Cake\Network\Http\Adapter\Stream::_send()`.

- **[.../src/Network/Http/Adapter/Stream.php#L258-L277](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.10/src/Network/Http/Adapter/Stream.php#L258-L277)**
- **[.../src/Network/Http/Adapter/Stream.php#L94-L110](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.10/src/Network/Http/Adapter/Stream.php#L94-L110)**

The response being malformed, like not containing a `HTTP/...` header could for example be one reason for such a failure. Maybe what you have there isn't a response at all, maybe the request didn't even made it through your firewall or something, but didn't caused an error. So, I'd suggest starting with inspecting `$meta` and `$content` and going from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll start digging.